# How to export a class using DrawerNavigation and import it in another class in React-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my React- Native project , I have App.js file as my default class. In this is class I have used DrawerNavigation. Here I have provided the code for my App.js class-

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  createStackNavigator,
  createAppContainer,
} from 'react-navigation';

import Screen1 from './pages/Screen1';
import Screen2 from './pages/Screen2';
import Screen3 from './pages/Screen3';

class NavigationDrawerStructure extends Component {
  toggleDrawer = () => {
    this.props.navigationProps.toggleDrawer();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)}>
          {/*Donute Button Image */}
          <Image
            source={require('./image/drawer.png')}
            style={{ width: 25, height: 25, marginLeft: 5 }}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const FirstActivity_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({

  First: {
    screen: Screen1,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Demo Screen 1',
      headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF9800',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),
  },
});


const Screen2_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({

  Second: {
    screen: Screen2,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Demo Screen 2',
      headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF9800',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),
  },
});

const Screen3_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Third: {
    screen: Screen3,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Demo Screen 3',
      headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF9800',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),
  },
});

const DrawerNavigatorExample = createDrawerNavigator({

  Screen1: {
    //Title
    screen: FirstActivity_StackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Demo Screen 1',
    },
  },
  Screen2: {
    //Title
    screen: Screen2_StackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Demo Screen 2',
    },
  },
  Screen3: {
    //Title
    screen: Screen3_StackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Demo Screen 3',
    },
  },
});

export default createAppContainer(DrawerNavigatorExample);
```

Now, the problem is I want to make another class as my default class and from that class I want to import App.js and then lauch the App.js class. But in the App.js class I already have one export-

```
export default createAppContainer(DrawerNavigatorExample);
```

And in React-native it doesn't allow me to export multiple modules.
So, if I want to Export the App.js file and use it inside the View of another class, then how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can only export one module as default.

you can use `export` only

```
export const AppRoute = createAppContainer(DrawerNavigatorExample);
```

to import that

```
import { AppRoute } from 'App.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can export default your class like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  createStackNavigator,
  createAppContainer,
} from 'react-navigation';

import Screen1 from './pages/Screen1';
import Screen2 from './pages/Screen2';
import Screen3 from './pages/Screen3';

class NavigationDrawerStructure extends Component {
  toggleDrawer = () => {
    this.props.navigationProps.toggleDrawer();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)}>
          {/*Donute Button Image */}
          <Image
            source={require('./image/drawer.png')}
            style={{ width: 25, height: 25, marginLeft: 5 }}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const FirstActivity_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({

  First: {
    screen: Screen1,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Demo Screen 1',
      headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF9800',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),
  },
});


const Screen2_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({

  Second: {
    screen: Screen2,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Demo Screen 2',
      headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF9800',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),
  },
});

const Screen3_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Third: {
    screen: Screen3,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Demo Screen 3',
      headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF9800',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),
  },
});

export const DrawerNavigatorExample = createAppContainer({

  Screen1: {
    //Title
    screen: FirstActivity_StackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Demo Screen 1',
    },
  },
  Screen2: {
    //Title
    screen: Screen2_StackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Demo Screen 2',
    },
  },
  Screen3: {
    //Title
    screen: Screen3_StackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Demo Screen 3',
    },
  },
});

export default new NavigationDrawerStructure();
```

Than, you can import like this:

```
import { DrawerNavigatorExample }, NavigationDrawerStructure from './App.js';
```

Comment: Nope! SyntaxError. Unexpected token. Basically, not happy with the comma.